# Given the partition list the ordered pairs in the corresponding equivalence relation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-partition

Given the partition $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{d,e\}$ of the set $S=\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, list the ordered pairs in
the corresponding equivalence relation.

I'm not really sure how to get started on this and would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordered pairs are going to be all those pairs of the form $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ belong to the same part.

There should be $3^2+2^2$ such pairs in this case.

Comment: So for example, in the set $\{a,b,c\}$ a couple of pairs would be $(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,c)$ etc?

Comment: yes, there should be nine of those.Don't forget (a,a) (b,b) and (c,c)

Comment: Sorry if this next question is a dumb question, but can $(a,a)$ be considered an ordered pair in $\{a,b,c\}$?

Comment: yes it can. since both of its elements are in that set.

Comment: An unrelated question, but does this question and questions regarding discrete mathematics fall under elementary set theory?  I read the tag and see that some of the things we cover in this class are topics under elementary set theory, but I just want to make sure I'm properly tagging my questions.

Comment: Yes, I think the answer is tagged appropriately.